# How to configure RocksDB matrics using kafka streams 3.2.0 in java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb, rocksdb-java

I need to use metrics mentioned in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-471%3A+Expose+RocksDB+Metrics+in+Kafka+Stream in java.
Is there any sample document available for printing the default values using java code ?
In case any different values need to be set then what will be code snippet ?
I need to print default values for those metrics.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Metrics would mostly all have default values of zero. Are you asking about the ConfigSetter?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I need to print the default values of them in my code.

Comment: As mentioned, there is no "default". Count/Average/Rate metrics would all start at zero for example. Also, you typically wouldn't write code to read the metrics. You can use tools like Prometheus JMX Exporter or Jolokia to expose the metrics, or otherwise use [JMX remote monitoring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/management/monitoring-and-management-using-jmx-technology.html#GUID-F08985BB-629A-4FBF-A0CB-8762DF7590E0) ... You also don't have access to "set custom metrics" internal to the RocksDB API. For that, you need to add MBeans to your app, such as by using MicroMeter.

Comment: How to populate these matrix on Grafana ?

Comment: Metrics... Not matrix... I don't know what you want to plot. But here's one that's for apps running in Kubernetes https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/13966-kafka-streams-dashboard/

Comment: okay any idea about Prometheus application ?

Comment: Just add the JMX exporter to your Kafka Streams app https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter

Comment: I am able to see only few metrics listed below by adding JMX reporter.                                                 prefix-scan-latency-avg ,range-latency-avg ,record-e2e-latency-max , range-rate ,flush-rate . Any idea about rocks dB metrics  ? @OneCricketeer

Comment: Well, RocksDB isnt a Java process, so it shouldn't have JMX metrics unless the Kafka API has other ways to extract those. You'd need to look at the Kafka source code to find those, however. As the wiki says - "_RocksDB's statistics can be accessed programmatically via JNI_". So if the Kafka code actually does that or not, I do not know

Comment: We can print the metrics using MetricsReporter class of Kafka.

Comment: Yes. And rather than print, you can also register them all in a Prometheus registry, or JMX beans